# Object object doesn't inherit from any object, then Object.prototype refers to what

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

Object is the final link in the prototype chain of any object because it doesn't inherits from any other object.

By definition: prototype is an object from which objects (or, child objects) inherit their properties. Like for example: any object In JavaScript (that directly inherit properties from Object),  inherits the toString () method from Object.

The question is, if Object doesn't inherit from anything, then Object.prototype refers to what?

Comment: Try this: console.log (Object.prototype). Returns Object {}, which contains a large set of methods.

Comment: No, it's not `Object` but rather `Object.prototype` that is the final link. (For *most* objects: it is possible to create an object not linked to it if you pass null to `Object.create()`.)

Comment: Then I guess it's easy to find out.

Comment: @nnnnnn—actually *null* is the end for [*all objects*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-the-object-prototype-object). `Object.create(null)` just creates a very short chain. ;-)

Comment: @RobG but I think it doesn't even forms any chain. If an object inherits from what Object.create (null)returns,  then there would be a chain. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Devashish—if a chain only has one link, is it a chain? :-) Implementations can do what they like, just so long as such an object has no inherited properties and [*Object.getPrototypeOf*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.getprototypeof) returns *null* and its *constructor* property is *undefined*.

Comment: @RobG You wrote' Object.create (null) just creates a very short chain'. Point of confusion was, does it even creates a chain.

Comment: @Devashish—every object has a `[[prototype]]` property that must reference an object or *null*, so to me `Object.create(null)` creates an object with a single thing on its prototptye chain, *null*. Does [*Object.prototype*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-the-object-prototype-object) have a prototype chain? It's semantics really. Whether an implementation actually creates a reference to *null* is moot.